# Is it possible to add an error code to an exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

To throw an exception, by the moment I am using this way?

```
throw new ArgumentException("My message");
```

But if a mtethod can throw an ArgumentException for many reasons, I would like to know the exact reason of the exception.

I know that I could use this away:

```
throw new ArgumentException("MyParamName", "MyMessage");
```

But this cases doesn't help so much if the same parameter can have many reasons to throw the ArgumentException. For example, I have a parameter in a method with two properties and one needs to be greater than 0 and the other one less than 0. I would like to send an error code, 001 when the first parameter is not greater than 0 and 002 when the second parameter is not less than 0. In this way. But I don't know if it is possible set an error code in the exception.

I could use this way:

```
throw new ArgumentException("My message " + "(001)");
```

At the end of the message I could add the error code, but I had to search for the substring (001). But I am wondering if there would be a better  option.

Another way it could be create my own exception, but if I have an ArgumentException, I think that create a new exception only to have a property for the error code and include the original exception it is little overhead.

So my question is, what is the best option? There are another solutions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could write your own override of ArgumentException with ErrorCode:

```
public class ArgumentExceptionEx : ArgumentException
{
    public int ErrorCode { get; }
    public ArgumentExceptionEx(string paramName, int errorCode)
        : base (paramName)    
    {
        ErrorCode = errorCode;
    }
}
```

after that you could throw new `ArgumentExceptionEx ("MyParamName", 1)` 
Or you cuold even make Enum for your second parameter if you have a predefined amount of error codes.

Comment: Thought of the same suggestion